# error when running sudo apt-get upgrade (linux-headers-generic related)

Tags: upgrade, kernel

i am trying to run sudo apt-get upgrade, but it says:

```
linux-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 5.4.0.51.54) but 5.4.0.48.51 is installed
```

to try to fix this, i manually downloaded the following packages from the ubuntu kernel team site and installed succesfully:

**linux-headers-5.6.10-050610_5.6.10-050610.202005052301_all.deb 

linux-image-unsigned-5.6.10-050610-generic_5.6.10-050610.202005052301_amd64.deb 

linux-modules-5.6.10-050610-generic_5.6.10-050610.202005052301_amd64.deb**

so when i run $ uname r it says:

```
~$ uname -r
5.6.10-050610-generic
```

i thought it would solve the problem, but i still get that same message from before installing. don't i have the updated version of the headers they need? why is that a problem? what even is the problem?

Comment: While it's really great that you decided to become a kernel tester, you seem to imply that may not have been your intent. Ubuntu 20.10 (and future 20.04.2) will use kernel 5.8, so your migration to 5.6 seems a bit of a dead-end.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, the current package for both `linux-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` is 5.4.0.52.55 (not 5.4.0.51.54)

I see four possibilities:

1. You forgot to run `sudo apt update`. This is the most common reason. Simply do so, and your problem will magically vanish like a morning fog.
2. If you recently did a release-upgrade, and you have other problems, then you might have had problems with your release-upgrade.

   It's common when folks add non-Ubuntu packages, third-party sources, PPAs, and other strange stuff, and then hope that apt can handle it magically. It cannot, which breaks upgrades. This is moderately common with LTS-to-LTS upgrades where folks don't keep track of what they installed two years ago.

   If this is what happened to you, then the easy solution is to backup your data and clean-install 20.04 to wipe away all that historical dreck.

   Best practice for release-upgrades is to uninstall all non-Ubuntu and wrong-version packages and sources *before* a release-upgrade; return your system to as close to stock condition as possible. Then release-upgrade, then restore your non-Ubuntu sources and package. Next time, try to do it that way.
3. On rare occasions, a metapackage (like `linux-headers-generic`) fails to upgrade. This usually happens when folks or their network connection are inconsistent about upgrades and delay normal apt upgrades for more than a few weeks. It's most often associated with no-space-left-on-device errors. You can test for this by looking at the metapackage version.

   In this example, the version number is current (5.4.0.52.55), so my system does NOT have this problem, and the solution below won't help.

   ```
   $ dpkg -l | grep linux-image-generic
   ii  linux-image-generic                        5.4.0.52.55
   ```

   If your system has an older version number that stubbornly won't change, then use `clean` to delete the metapackage from your local cache (thereby forcing apt to download a fresh copy) then reinstall the metapackage. Finally run a normal apt upgrade.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt clean linux-headers-generic
   sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
4. If your upgrade habit is to use a mixture of GUI and Shell, then it's rare-but-possible that your system might have been caught up in [*phased updates*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates).

   Simply run an apt-update/upgrade from the shell instead of using the GUI tools. Shell tools are not subject to phased updates.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

Comment: your answer was great, very thorough and thoughtful, which makes me rly sad to report i had the exact same results. i actually did, first of all, run apt-get update before apt-get upgrade before the problem started! i found the archives i added in my question (the ones you commented saying they seemed like a 'dead end') googling how to solve this same problem. apparently, they were not only not related to my problem, as another problem. i think i might give up on ubuntu altogether after this. since i upgraded to 20.04 my archives wont show on search and this kind of issue became a constant. :(

Comment: i have no idea, for instance, what the dead end issue is, as i was just trying the solution presented here: https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/
for this same problem i presented here. my terminal is in portuguese and i think endlessly copying and pasteing what it says here would lead nowhere either, as something could get lost in translation. i'm v thankful for ur kind response and really regret i wasnt able to use it.

Comment: yes i did (the upgrade)! ok, that seems likely and could possibly explain my other problems, i will try that now! thank you v much

Comment: Big edit to add the release-upgrade possibility.

Comment: thank you you were 100% right, the clean install solved all my problems!

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned that the easiest way to fix dependencies (removing what's not needed, and adding what is) is to run this:

`sudo apt full-upgrade`

This handles adding/removing of certain packages that the normal upgrade option does not, and may potentially resolve your problem.

Had a similar issue with held back packages preventing upgrades. using the command above handled it immediately.

Comment: No problem. If it helped, then I'm glad. :)